# How to fix this unhandled rejection error in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

> I am trying to signup the user but facing this unhandled error. How to
> fix this unhandled rejection error in react?. I have tried so many
> times to find the exact problem but was unable to find why it occur.

```
   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qafqt.png

    import React, { useState } from "react";
    import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
    import Layout from "../core/Layout";
    import { signup } from "../auth";

    const Signup = () => {
    const [values, setValues] = useState({
    name: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
    error: "",
    success: false,
  });

    const { name, email, password, success, error } = values;

    const handleChange = (name) => (event) => {
     setValues({ ...values, error: false, [name]: event.target.value });
     };

    const clickSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setValues({ ...values, error: false });
    signup({ name, email, password }).then((data) => {
      if (data.error) {
        setValues({ ...values, error: data.error, success: false });
      } else {
        setValues({
          ...values,
          name: "",
          email: "",
          password: "",
          error: "",
          success: true,
        });
       }
      });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt. Then if one of the answers works for you mark them as [answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your error line with this and try

```
if(data && data.error){
```

Comment: @pujan Did it help you?

Comment: Please accept the answer by clicking on tick besides the answer if it helped you. Thanks :)

Comment: Raghvender Kataria   I used that the error is solved but the data is not saved in mongodb though using post man it is working

Comment: The code that you pasted in the question is not having the code for API call

Comment: It looks like that your code for API call is having some issues due to which you are not able to store data. You can try debugging that

Comment: I am getting Error: A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to the actual error object in development.

Comment: hmm that is the reason that your data is not getting stored to DB. You need to resolve CORS error. This may be done at server end where it can accept requests from your domain

Comment: Try exploring: "heroku" for cross domain requests, it can help you

Comment: @ Raghvender Kataria currently I am not using it for production so that might not help. Is there any other reason so that this might occur

Comment: It depends purely on your configurations